# React component with state triggers animation in subcomponent when the state of parent component is changed

Tags: css, reactjs

ProjectsSection component renders a document section with header and cards. A header animation should be triggered when the header is visible on the screen for the 1st time and run only once. However when I added a state to the ProjectsSection component with every state change a header animation runs and what is surprising to me only a part of it (letters/ spans that are children to h2 move, but brackets/ pseudoelements on h2 don't). In my project I use css modules for styling.

I have tried to wrap SectionHeader component in React.memo but it does not help.

Main component:

```
const ProjectsSection = () => {
  const [openProjectCardId, setOpenProjectCardId] = useState('');

  return (
    <section id="projects" className="section">
      <div className="container">
        <SectionHeader>Projects</SectionHeader>

        <div className={styles.content_wrapper}>
          {projects.map((project, ind) => (
            <Project
              key={project.id}
              project={project}
              ind={ind}
              isOpen={openProjectCardId === project.id}
              setOpenProjectCardId={setOpenProjectCardId}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

SectionHeader component:

```
const SectionHeader = ({ children }) => {
  const headerRef = useIntersection(
    styles.sectionHeader__isVisible,
    { rootMargin: '0px 0px -100px 0px', threshold: 1 },
  );

  const textToLetters = children.split('').map((letter) => {
    const style = !letter ? styles.space : styles.letter;
    return (
      <span className={style} key={nanoid()}>
        {letter}
      </span>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.sectionHeader_wrapper} ref={headerRef}>
      <h2 className={styles.sectionHeader}>{textToLetters}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Css

```
.sectionHeader_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  // other properties

  &::before {
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    // other properties
  }

  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    // other properties
  }
}

.sectionHeader {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  // other properties
}

.letter {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(100%) skew(0deg, 20deg);
}

.sectionHeader__isVisible .letter {
  animation: typeletter .25s ease-out forwards;
}
```

useIntersection hook

```
const useIntersection = (
  activeClass,
  { root = null, rootMargin = '0px', threshold = 1 },
  dependency = [],
  unobserveAfterFirstIntersection = true
) => {
  const elementRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const options: IntersectionObserverInit = {
      root,
      rootMargin,
      threshold,
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observerObj) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (unobserveAfterFirstIntersection) {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classList.add(activeClass);
            observerObj.unobserve(entry.target);
          }
        } else if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          entry.target.classList.add(activeClass);
        } else {
          entry.target.classList.remove(activeClass);
        }
      });
    }, options);

    // if (!elementRef.current) return;
    if (elementRef.current) {
      observer.observe(elementRef.current);
    }
  }, [...dependency]);

  return elementRef;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem.
This was apparently about textToLetters variable created every time the state of parent component was changing.
I used useMemo to keep this value and now animation is not triggered anymore.

```
const textToLetters = (text) =>
  text.split('').map((letter) => {
    const style = !letter ? styles.space : styles.letter;
    return (
      <span className={style} key={nanoid()}>
        {letter}
      </span>
    );
  });

const SectionHeader= ({ children }) => {
  const headerRef = useIntersection(
    styles.sectionHeader__isVisible,
    { rootMargin: '0px 0px -100px 0px', threshold: 1 },
    [children]
  );
  const letters = React.useMemo(() => textToLetters(children), [children]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.sectionHeader_wrapper} ref={headerRef}>
      <h2 className={styles.sectionHeader}>{letters}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```